# Copy an array to another array on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am searching a neat way of copying the array list to another based on some condition. I dont want to copy element by element. this is time taken also, and ofcourse with lots of lines

**MYJSON**

```
$scope.leadsDataSource=[{
            id: 1,
            type: 1,
            typeName: "Lead",
            client: 1,
            clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB",
            status: 2,
            statusName: "Open",
            stage: 2,
            stageName: "Stage 2",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        }, {
            id: 2,
            type: 1,
            typeName: "Lead",
            client: 2,
            clientName: "Solina Sweden AB",
            marking: "Marking for Solina Sweden AB",
            status: 1,
            statusName: "Closed",
            stage: 3,
            stageName: "Stage 3",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        }, {
            id: 3,
            type: 2,
            typeName: "Opportunity",
            client: 3,
            clientName: "H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB",
            marking: "Marking for H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB",
            status: 3,
            statusName: "Pending",
            stage: 4,
            stageName: "Stage 4",
            leadValue: 1,
            probability: 1,
            issuer: 1,
            issuerName: "Sales",
            handler: 1,
            handlerName: "Sales",
            created: 1462345200000,
            createdString: "2016-05-04"
        }];
```

**Condition Script**

```
 var dataSource=[];
        angular.forEach($scope.leadsDataSource, function (value, key) {
            if(value.typeName=='Lead'){
                 //**copy the row to dataSource**
            }
        });
```

Is there any neat way, where I dont have to push each element??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.filter(function (a) {
        return a.typeName=='Lead';
    });
```

```js
var $scope = {},
    dataSource;

$scope.leadsDataSource = [{ id: 1, type: 1, typeName: "Lead", client: 1, clientName: "Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", marking: "Marking for Ljungbloms Elektriska AB", status: 2, statusName: "Open", stage: 2, stageName: "Stage 2", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }, { id: 2, type: 1, typeName: "Lead", client: 2, clientName: "Solina Sweden AB", marking: "Marking for Solina Sweden AB", status: 1, statusName: "Closed", stage: 3, stageName: "Stage 3", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }, { id: 3, type: 2, typeName: "Opportunity", client: 3, clientName: "H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB", marking: "Marking for H & M Hennes & Mauritz GBC AB", status: 3, statusName: "Pending", stage: 4, stageName: "Stage 4", leadValue: 1, probability: 1, issuer: 1, issuerName: "Sales", handler: 1, handlerName: "Sales", created: 1462345200000, createdString: "2016-05-04" }];

dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.filter(function (a) {
    return a.typeName == 'Lead';
});

console.log(dataSource);
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Comment: thats the power of an ide.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the native [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/filter) method:

```
var dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.filter(function(value){
  return value.typeName == 'Lead';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one (neat) solution:

```
       var dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.filter(function(item) {
          return item.typeName ==='Lead';
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a deep copy you need, then use `angular.copy`

```
var dataSource=[];
        angular.forEach($scope.leadsDataSource, function (value, key) {
            if(value.typeName=='Lead'){
                dataSource.push(angular.copy(value))     
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you you use the old classic map.

```
   var dataSource = $scope.leadsDataSource.map(function (item) {
        if(item.typeName === 'Lead') return item;    
    });
```